# With Django m2m_changed signal, is there a way to know which relation was removed?

Tags: django, m2m

With [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/), you have both pre_remove and post_remove signals. But is there a way to determine which m2m relation is being removed in either of these hooks?

I know with post_add for instance you can obtain the most recent relation as follows:

```
from_collection = instance.name.through.objects.last().from_name
to_collection = instance.name.through.objects.last().to_name
```

Im looking for the same except for a removal. Any way this can be done?

Comment: According to the documentation “pk_set” will be a set of all primary keys removed from the relation. Is that what you’re looking for?

Comment: Exactly what i needed, thank you. Glanced over it at least 10 times.